# NodeJS install error on CentOs 6.3

Tags: node.js, unix, centos, v8

I had Node.js installed on my server. Yesterday, I deleted it with `yum erase nodejs` and now I'm trying to install the new Node.js. I've tried `yum install nodejs-compat-symlinks npm` but it ends with the error:

> Running rpm_check_debug 
>   Running Transaction Test
>
> Transaction Check Error:
>   file /usr/bin/node conflicts between
>   attempted installs of nodejs-compat-symlinks-1-1.el6.noarch and
>   nodejs-0.10.5-3.el6.x86_64
>
> file /usr/include/node conflicts between
>   attempted installs of nodejs-compat-symlinks-1-1.el6.noarch and
>   nodejs-devel-0.10.5-3.el6.x86_64

How I may install Node.js on server now?

P.S. I installed Node.js with this manual:

> wget
>   http://patches.fedorapeople.org/oldnode/repocfg/el/nodejs-stable-release.noarch.rpm
>   yum localinstall --nogpgcheck nodejs-stable-release.noarch.rpm
>
> Edit /etc/yum.repos.d/nodejs-stable.repo. Comment out the mirrorlist
>   and use for [nodejs-stable] the baseurl:
>   baseurl=http://patches.fedorapeople.org/oldnode/stable/el$releasever/$basearch/
>
> and for [nodejs-stable-source] also comment out the mirrorlist and use
>   for [nodejs-stable-source] the baseurl:
>   baseurl=http://patches.fedorapeople.org/oldnode/stable/el$releasever/SRPMS/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a conflicting package that you didn't erase with Node when you ran `yum erase nodejs`. `nodejs-devel-0.10.5-3.el6.x86_64` is a completely separate package.

http://pkgs.org/centos-6-rhel-6/epel-testing-x86_64/nodejs-0.10.9-1.el6.x86_64.rpm.html
http://pkgs.org/centos-6-rhel-6/epel-testing-x86_64/nodejs-devel-0.10.9-1.el6.x86_64.rpm.html

Try running `yum erase nodejs-devel`, and then try to `yum install nodejs-compat-symlinks npm` again.